# Jackson, Hibernate Validator, and Spring MVC: combining them together

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, hibernate-validator, http-error

I hope you're fine:

```
public class UserDTO extends AbstractDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2724997313065531109L;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]+$")
    @Length(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Length(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 6, max = 30)
    private String password;

    private String gender;

    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 13)
    @Length(min = 8, max = 20)
    private String mobile;

    @Length(min = 6, max = 30)
    private String confirmPassword;

    @NotNull
    @Past
    private Date birthDate;
```

I'm using Jackson to submit JSON object in Spring MVC, moreover I'm using Hibernate Validator.

For the above DTO, when I'm trying to submit a json object with username length is less than the minimum length in the class **@Length(min = 3, max = 30)**, I got **http 400 bad request**.
Why the annotation of hibernate validation  is tightly coupled with Jackson? and How can I get rid of this error?

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: post your controller handler please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring3 doesn't work @valid when json request I got 400 Bad Request error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183102/spring3-doesnt-work-valid-when-json-request-i-got-400-bad-request-error)

Comment: <code>@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
public String registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody final UserDTO userDTO,
   final HttpSession session, final HttpServletResponse response,
   final HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap model,
   final BindingResult bindingResult) {</code>

Comment: @mserioli I think your answer is in my previous comment..

Comment: Thanks @mserioli for your response, but that should not be happen because Jackson is exist to do mapping only not validation. it should not be related moreover the solution is just work around not facing the problem. Thanks again :D

Comment: I know that jackson serialize/deserialize json. But as the answer in the link states, after json is converted into an object comes validation that causes an HttpMessageNotReadableException. Maybe I have not understand your question ;)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting "Bad Request" because of validation and not because of json deserialization problem? Remove @Valid and other validation annotations and try then.

Comment: You are explicitly stating that you want the POJO to be @Valid. Therefor Spring runs the validators and since it's not valid it returns HTTP 400. It has nothing to do with JSON deserialization, it's strickly Spring MVC behavior. If you do not want the POJO to be valid, simple remove the `@Valid` annotation

Comment: Thanks for all :) , I need to make validation too beside the serialization, @geoand you're right, it's spring mvc behaviour, if the POJO is not valid, then an exception is thrown, we can handle it by putting the exception handler in the controller:   next comment

Comment: here is the exception handler:                                             @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
 public String exceptionHandler(
   final MethodArgumentNotValidException errors,
   final HttpSession session, final HttpServletResponse response,
   final HttpServletRequest request) {
  System.out.println(errors.getBindingResult().hasErrors());
  // final BindingResult bindingResult = errors.getBindingResult(); ......

Comment: The question here is: how can I get the POJO in the exception handler? to be able to send back the response to the user, that response should contain the old data(old POJO, the user should not enter his data again) and error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following link:
http://ppettitau.wordpress.com/tag/requestbody/
,You will find how to combine Hibernate Validator, Jacson, and Spring MVC.
The link is providing a complete request life cycle, the client sends request and receive a response in AJAX way.
The response contains the error messages that you want to show for the user.